# random error while filling datatable in asp.net/ado.net/sql server web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datatable, ado.net

```
My public class (dbLibrary.vb)

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class dbLibrary

Public dbCon As SqlConnection
Public Constring As String
Public dbCmd As SqlCommand
Public dbAdp As SqlDataAdapter
Public dbDTable As DataTable
Dim PmtName As String, PmtValue
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim MySqlTransact As SqlTransaction

Public Sub New(Optional ByVal OpenConnection As Boolean = False)
    Constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString
    dbCon = New SqlConnection(Constring)
    If OpenConnection = True Then
        dbCon.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FetchRecordsDataTable(ByVal CmdType As Integer, ByVal CmdString As String, Optional ByVal PmtValue As Integer = -100, Optional ByVal PmtName As String = "-") As DataTable
    'CmdType = 1 if Stored Procedure, CmdType = 2 if Text, CmdType = 3 if Table Direct
    dbCmd = New SqlCommand
    If CmdType = 1 Then dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    If CmdType = 2 Then dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    'If CmdType = 3 Then Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect 'Not Supported in SQL
    If PmtValue <> -100 Then
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PmtName, PmtValue)
    End If
    dbCmd.CommandText = CmdString
    dbCmd.Connection = dbCon
    dbAdp = New SqlDataAdapter
    dbAdp.SelectCommand = dbCmd
    dbDTable = New DataTable
    dbAdp.Fill(dbDTable)
    Return dbDTable
End Function

 Public Function FetchRecordsDataTableByPmtArray(ByVal StoredProcedureName As String, ByVal ParameterArrayList As ArrayList, Optional ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean = False) As DataTable
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    dbCmd = New SqlCommand
    dbCmd.Connection = dbCon
    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dbCmd.CommandText = StoredProcedureName
    dbCmd.CommandTimeout = 300
    For Ctr = 0 To ParameterArrayList.Count - 1 Step 2
        PmtName = ParameterArrayList(Ctr)
        PmtValue = ParameterArrayList(Ctr + 1)
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PmtName, PmtValue)
    Next
    dbAdp = New SqlDataAdapter
    dbAdp.SelectCommand = dbCmd
    dbDTable = New DataTable
    dbAdp.Fill(dbDTable)
    If CloseConnection = True Then
        dbCon.Close()
    End If
    Return dbDTable
End Function

Public Sub CloseConnection()
    If dbCon.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        dbCon.Close()
    End If
    dbCmd = Nothing
    dbAdp = Nothing
    dbDTable = Nothing
    dbCon = Nothing
End Sub

End Class

My Module (Module1.vb)

Imports dbLibrary

Module Module1

Dim dbobj As dbLibrary

Function getStates() As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dbobj = New dbLibrary
    dt = dbobj.FetchRecordsDataTable(1, "spGetStates")
    dbobj.CloseConnection()
    dbobj = Nothing
    Return dt
End Function

Function getDistricts(ByVal arrList As ArrayList) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dbobj = New dbLibrary
    dt = dbobj.FetchRecordsDataTableByPmtArray("spGetDistricts", arrList)
    dbobj.CloseConnection()
    dbobj = Nothing
    Return dt
End Function
End Module
```

I have created `dbLibrary` object in web pages to access database. 
`CloseConnection()` method is always called in code. Now errors occur randomly whenever a function is called returning datatable

The errors are:

`"Column 'XXXXX' does not belong to table"
"'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'x'"`

Maybe datatable is overwriting for 2 concurrent user.

Comment: Can you post your code? It will help us help you debug the issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are **Opening** and **Closing** the connection in separate functions. You should **Open** and **Close** every connection inside each function that [connects to SQL](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm).

> The Close() method in SqlConnection Class is used to close the
>   Database Connection. The Close method rolls back any pending
>   transactions and releases the Connection from the SQL Server Database.

Remove the **Open** and **Close** from the other functions and put them in the functions that retrieve the data from SQL.

FetchRecordsDataTable Example:

```
Public Function FetchRecordsDataTable(ByVal CmdType As Integer, ByVal CmdString As String, Optional ByVal PmtValue As Integer = -100, Optional ByVal PmtName As String = "-") As DataTable
    'CmdType = 1 if Stored Procedure, CmdType = 2 if Text, CmdType = 3 if Table Direct
    dbCmd = New SqlCommand
    If CmdType = 1 Then dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    If CmdType = 2 Then dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    'If CmdType = 3 Then Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect 'Not Supported in SQL
    If PmtValue <> -100 Then
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PmtName, PmtValue)
    End If

    dbCon.Open()
    dbCmd.CommandText = CmdString
    dbCmd.Connection = dbCon
    dbAdp = New SqlDataAdapter
    dbAdp.SelectCommand = dbCmd
    dbDTable = New DataTable
    dbAdp.Fill(dbDTable)
    dbCon.Close()

    Return dbDTable
End Function
```

FetchRecordsDataTableByPmtArray Example:

```
 Public Function FetchRecordsDataTableByPmtArray(ByVal StoredProcedureName As String, ByVal ParameterArrayList As ArrayList, Optional ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean = False) As DataTable
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    dbCmd = New SqlCommand

    dbCon.Open()

    dbCmd.Connection = dbCon
    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dbCmd.CommandText = StoredProcedureName
    dbCmd.CommandTimeout = 300

    For Ctr = 0 To ParameterArrayList.Count - 1 Step 2
        PmtName = ParameterArrayList(Ctr)
        PmtValue = ParameterArrayList(Ctr + 1)
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PmtName, PmtValue)
    Next

    dbAdp = New SqlDataAdapter
    dbAdp.SelectCommand = dbCmd
    dbDTable = New DataTable
    dbAdp.Fill(dbDTable)

    dbCon.Close()

    Return dbDTable
End Function
```

As a best practice. Wrap the above code inside a [Try Catch Finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) block. If you wrap the code inside a Try Catch Finally, you can close the connection even if there is an error.

```
Try
    dbCon.Open()
    'Do database work
    .
    .
    .
Catch ex As Exception
    'Handle Exception
    .
    .
    .
Finally
    dbCon.Close()
End Try
```

Microsoft also offers another good set of examples for working with [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,   Although we are opening and closing connection in different functions but we are doing it with the object of public class. We create object 'dbobj', it calls the constructor to initialize and open the connection and then after accessing data we call dbobj.CloseConnection to close the connection. So i think there is no problem with it because same object is used to open and close the connection